# Python - Multiple persistent modifiable rectangle selector

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, plot, computer-vision

I am currently trying to display an image with several highlighted and modifiable region of interests. I want to solve it by using for example the rectangleselector from the `matplotlib.widgets`.

The issue is just I am not able to blend in multiple persistent dragable resizeable bounding boxes.

The example is [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/widgets/rectangle_selector.html).

If you have an alternative approach please let me know.

I would like to have like in the aforementioned example multiple rectangle selector objects. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you face? Which action would you consider to select one or the other of those selectors? What have you tried in this respect?

Comment: [Context: I would show a photo of a traffic scene, and I would let the programm create after a 2D object detection several bounding boxes. I would like to give the user the possibility to modify the position and size. The issue is: I can just make only one interactive persistent rectangle. I do not know how to append it, to have several interactive concurrent interactive rectangles.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a nice library as an alternative: [PyQtGraph - ROI](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/roi.html).

[Here](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/downloads/0.10.0/pyqtgraph-0.10.0-deb/pyqtgraph-0.10.0/examples/ROIExamples.py) is a nice code example:

```
v3 = w3.addViewBox(row=1, col=0, lockAspect=True) # adds a content area 
                                                  # to the existing layout

r3a = pg.ROI([0,0], [10,10])  #creates a bounding box which i need
v3.addItem(r3a) #adding it to the scene
## handles scaling horizontally around center
r3a.addScaleHandle([1, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5]) #append the box with dragable handles
r3a.addScaleHandle([0, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5]) #for nice resizing purposes

## handles scaling vertically from opposite edge
r3a.addScaleHandle([0.5, 0], [0.5, 1])
r3a.addScaleHandle([0.5, 1], [0.5, 0])

## handles scaling both vertically and horizontally
r3a.addScaleHandle([1, 1], [0, 0])
r3a.addScaleHandle([0, 0], [1, 1])
```

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.